# Extract a substring from a string without using the library function.[C# Console Application]

Tags: c#

My Solution for Question 13 on https://www.w3resource.com/csharp-exercises/string/index.php

```
        Console.Write("Please enter your word : ");
        string word = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Starting position : ");
        int start = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Number of letters : ");
        int numberOfLetters = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int x = word.Length - numberOfLetters;

        int end = word.Length - x;

        for (int counter = start; counter <= end; counter++)
        {
            Console.Write(word[counter]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Please summarise the problem statement (in your own words, of course).  The link may be helpful while it lasts, but questions are expected to be complete without needing external resources.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are not really extracting a substring, you are only printing a substring.

A string consists of single characters of type `char`. Create an array of chars and then convert it to string

```
var characters = new char[numberOfLetters];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLetters; i++) {
    characters[i] = word[i + start];
}
string output = new String(characters);
```

---

You are doing a strange calculation

```
int x = word.Length - numberOfLetters;
int end = word.Length - x;
```

If you insert the first expression for `x` into the second, you get:

```
int end = word.Length - (word.Length - numberOfLetters);
```

which is equivalent to

```
int end = word.Length - word.Length + numberOfLetters;
```

or

```
int end = numberOfLetters;
```

which is not correct. Simply add `start` and `numberOfLetters` to get the exclusive upper bound. If printing the substring is a solution, then you can write:

```
int max = start + numberOfLetters;
for (int i = start; i < max; i++) {
    Console.Write(word[i]);
}
```